# ¿Como hacer una clase que soporte todas las implementaciones permitidas de una interfaz?

Tags: java

Tengo una duda sobre como hacer una clase que soporte todas las implementaciones de una interfaz, osea tengo una clase A que tiene que poder administrar cualquier clase B que tenga implementada una interfaz C.

Este es un ejercicio de el libro de Cosmina Pro Spring 5 en la pagina 81 del libro:

**Interfaz C**

```
public interface ArtworkSender {
    void sendArtwork(String artworkPath, Recipient recipient);

    String getFriendlyName();

    String getShortName();
}
```

**Clase B** que implementa a la **interfaz C**

```
public class FtpArtworkSender implements ArtworkSender {
    @Override
    public void sendArtwork(String artworkPath, Recipient recipient) {
        // ftp logic here...
    }

    @Override
    public String getFriendlyName() {
        return "File Transfer Protocol";
    }

    @Override
    public String getShortName() {
        return "ftp";
    }
}
```

y la clase A que se llama `ArtworkManager` que se encuentra totalmente vacia, alguien tiene un ejemplo sobre el tema gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> lo que no entiendo es que dice que implemente una clase ArtworkManager
>   que admita todas las implementaciones de la Artwork-Sender interface,
>   no entiendo como hacer esto.

Lo que significa es que la lógica del sistema se programa en base a la interface `ArtowrkSender` que describe el comportamiento que debe tener cualquier clase que se utilice en ese lugar.

Luego para que sistema funcione se debe crear una clase que se pueda instanciar y que cumpla con dicho comportamiento. El ejemplo que da es es de una clase `ArtworkManager`. Entonces lo que debs programar es:

```
public class ArworkManager implements ArtworkSender {
  /* Acá todos los metodos que declara ArtworkSender */
}
```

Y vos debes codificar los metodos que se declaran en `ArtworkSender`.

De esta forma la programación del sistema queda desacoplada de las clases que implementan la funcionalidad. Lo unico que tenes que hacer es que Spring inyecte un bean de `ArtworkManager` donde se utilice la interface `ArtworkSender`.

Y el desacoplamiento se refiere a que se puede hacer otra clase `SuperArtworkManager` que también implemente los metodos de `ArtworkSender`, pero que resulevan los metodos declarados de una forma diferente que `ArtworkManager`. Y para que el sistema utilice esta nueva clase, solo hay que cambiar el bean que se inyecta donde se usa `ArtworkSender`, que en lugar de ser `ArtworkManager`, sea una instancia de `SuperArtworkManager`.

Comment: Hola gracias, pero no estoy entendiendo jejeje, no se si estoy un confundido, si tienes algun material que pueda explicar eso por favor

Comment: Busca información sobre "programar contra interfaces".